# Symfony 3 PhpUnit submit form

Tags: php, testing, phpunit, symfony

I try to test my php form in my admin with this code :

```
    $client = $this->createAuthorizedClient();
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/user/edit/1');

    $form = $crawler->selectButton('Save')->form();
    $form['sf_guard_user[lastName]']  = 'lastname';
    $crawler = $client->submit($form);
    $form->get('sf_guard_user[lastName]')->setValue('Richardson');
    $client->submit($form);
    $response = $client->getResponse();
```

My function createAuthorizedClient is here :

```
    protected function createAuthorizedClient()
{
    $client = static::createClient();
    $container = $client->getContainer();

    $session = $container->get('session');
    $userManager = $container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
    $loginManager = $container->get('fos_user.security.login_manager');
    $firewallName = $container->getParameter('fos_user.firewall_name');

    $user = $userManager->findUserByUsername('ASSELIN');
    $loginManager->logInUser($firewallName, $user);

    $container->get('session')->set('_security_' . $firewallName,
        serialize($container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()));
    $container->get('session')->save();
    $client->getCookieJar()->set(new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId()));

    return $client;
}
```

But when I launch my test I have this error in my $response :

```
{"code":500,"message":"A Token was not found in the TokenStorage."}"
```

The complete stack trace is here :

```
    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response {#2362
        +headers: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag {#2372
            #computedCacheControl: array:1 [
            "no-cache" => true
        ]
        #cookies: []
        #headerNames: array:3 [
          "cache-control" => "Cache-Control"
          "content-type" => "Content-Type"
          "allow" => "Allow"
        ]
        #headers: array:3 [
          "cache-control" => array:1 [
                0 => "no-cache"
            ]
          "content-type" => array:1 [
                0 => "application/json;"
            ]
          "allow" => array:1 [
                0 => "PUT"
            ]
        ]
        #cacheControl: []
      }
      #content: "{"code":500,"message":"A Token was not found in the TokenStorage."}"
      #version: "1.1"
      #statusCode: 500
      #statusText: "Internal Server Error"
      #charset: "UTF-8"
    }
```

I try to find a solution, but I don't understand why I have this error. Is it possible to explain me my error ? The form is submit with put method directly in the api.

Best regards,

Benoit

Comment: Gratulations, you've just discovered why Service Locator is an anti-pattern. ;-)

Comment: Did you grep the source code for "A Token was not found in the TokenStorage." to see what logic is being triggered?

Comment: The source code is above. It's the result of $response.

Comment: The exception comes from the AuthenticationListener and tells you that the requested token was not found. This hints at your session not being saved. This could be caused by a misconfigured session in `config.yml` or maybe an issue with your `security.yml`, e.g. `stateless: true`? Have you checked whether a session file is being written after calling `$session->save()`?

Comment: I check my security.yml and stateless is set to true. I try to write something in my session like $container->get('session')->set('test', 'toto'); and when I verify session test exist with good value "toto"

Answer (score 0):

I fix my problem with add http_basic in my security.yml :

```
security:
    firewalls:
        wsse_secured:
            stateless: false
            http_basic: ~
```